# Fetch API POST, not sending <form> data

Tags: javascript, fetch

I keep getting a 500 error server when I try to submit form data to my API `/users/signup`. I verified that the API works using Postman so I think the way I am doing my fetch post is wrong. What is the best practice here?

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("create_user").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const signup = {
        username: document.querySelector("#create_username").value.toString(),
        email: document.querySelector("#create_email").value.toString(),
        password: document.querySelector("#create_password").value.toString()
    }
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("json", JSON.stringify(signup));
    fetch('/users/signup', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form class="hide" id="sign_up_form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <h3>Sign up</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="create_username">Username</label>
            <input id="create_username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="create_email">Email</label>
            <input id="create_email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="create_password">Password</label>
            <input id="create_password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <small id="passwordHelp" class="text-muted">
                Must be at least 8 characters long
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row flex-end">
        <div class="form-group col-auto">
            <button id="create_user" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mb-2">Sign up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <span class="mr-2">Already have an account?</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="login_btn">Login</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to add  headers in Fetch API:-
`headers : {
 "content-type" : "application/json"
}`

Comment: it seems some problem in your API code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a form object, you can directly send the json data to your backend.

Add yous json data in the body and the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header in the request.

> The `value` property of the `querySelector` method will always return string, you don't need to call `toString` method on it.

Try this.

```
document.getElementById("create_user").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const signup = {
        username: document.querySelector("#create_username").value,
        email: document.querySelector("#create_email").value,
        password: document.querySelector("#create_password").value
    }
    fetch('/users/signup', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(signup)
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
});
```

Comment: alongside your answer I added `headers: new Headers(),` and everything is working now, thanks for your help